# Compare two pandas dataframes and replace value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the following two pandas dataframes:

```
df1
    A B  C
 0  1 2  1
 1  7 3  6
 2  3 10 11

df2
    A B C
 0  2 0 2
 1  8 4 7
```

Where A,B and C are column headings of both dataframes.

I am trying to compare columns of `df1` to columns of `df2` such that the first row in `df2` is the lower bound and the second row is the upper bound. Any values in `df1` outside the lower and upper bound (column wise) needs to be replaced with `NaN`.

So in this example the output should be:

```
    A    B   C
0   nan  2   nan
1    7   3   6
2    3   nan nan
```

As a basic I am trying `df1[df1 < df2] = np.nan`, but this does not work. I have also tried `.where()` but not getting any success.

Would appreciate some help here, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

```
df=df1.where(df1.ge(df2.iloc[0])&df1.lt(df2.iloc[1]))
     A    B    C
0  NaN  2.0  NaN
1  7.0  3.0  6.0
2  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
lower = df1 < df2.iloc[0, :]
upper = df1 > df2.iloc[1, :]

df1[lower | upper] = np.nan

print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  2.0  NaN
1  7.0  3.0  6.0
2  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one with `df.clip` and `mask`:

```
df1.mask(df1.ne(df1.clip(lower = df2.loc[0],upper = df1.loc[1],axis=1)))
```

---

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  2.0  NaN
1  7.0  3.0  6.0
2  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach using `between`,

```
df1.apply(lambda x:x.where(x.between(*df2.values, False)), axis=1)
```